# What kind of keyword research is helpful for news websites?

Tags: seo, keywords

I am adding a "**news**" section to my website.

I understand news stories are based on recent events. Hence, a conventional keyword research using data generated over time (like historical search volume, competition, etc) will not help. In that case, what kind of data should one look for?

Comment: You are right. News traditionally goes to trend searches which is handled differently in the algos. Search is not about keywords but whole language. Search is continually changing. Write thorough content and make sure that what you write can be understood using semantic analysis meaning properly formatted and clear in meaning. You do not have to chase keywords. Just cover the topic well and let the search engines do what they do well. Cheers!!

Comment: I removed your second question for two reasons:   Only one question per post in permitted here.   Your second question about "is it worth is" was asking for opinions and would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

News aren't mandatory new. News based on recent events is only one kind of news. News is everything, what one is interesting and looking for.

From this point of view, any topic could be an evergreen. Curate and compile information to a topic with public interest over time - and you get an evergreen content to evergreen topic.

Don't let yourself be guided by Google trends - do be guided by your interest. Your interest isn't unique - there are always some guys and gals interesting in the same. Share an expertise, research keywords which are mostly used to describe it - and your are safe.

Answer (score 3):

In order to rank a news site, you first have to acknowledge that you are competing with the big boys such as ABC and NYTimes. In order to rank against them, you are going to need to have excellent articles with longtail keywords related to a search. And you're probably going to need content and stories that the major sites  haven't jumped on yet or published.

For instance, a short tail keyword such as example.com/thePatriots will have a much harder time ranking for anything than a long tail keyword such as example.com/The-Patriots-Lose-The-Superbowl-After-Missing-A-Field-Goal

Being a successful news site operator is similar to being a successful journalist. You want to break the biggest stories that everyone is interested in and that are most relevant before everyone else does.